# Fail to load resource error : the server responded with a status of 404(not found)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a website to present a project, and I have to do a slideshow with several objects that can be seen at the same time. In order to do that I've planned to use this: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

I've followed the tutorial and just tried to do a simple example to see how it works, the problem is with the jquery or the slick resources I think...  But since I'm not an expert in that stuff I don't find the solution, it keeps telling me: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".

If someone knows how to solve the problem it would be a great help :D (I'm sure it's no big deal but...).

I've tried to change the place of the links in the document thinking it might be that.

I've downloaded the file from slick and put it in my folder already.

This is in the header

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

This is the part in the body

```html
<div class="testslicktrack">
    <div><h4>test1</h4></div>
    <div><h4>test2</h4></div>
    <div><h4>test3</h4></div>
    <div><h4>test4</h4></div>
    <div><h4>test5</h4></div>
    <div><h4>test6/h4></div>
</div>  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.testslicktrack').slick({
      dots: true,
      infinite: false,
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 4,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1024,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            infinite: true,
            dots: true
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 600,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Have you copied the `slick.css` and `slick.min.js` file in specified path.

Comment: On which resource it is giving you an error?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry i forgot to tell about that, it's on slick.css and slick.min.js

Comment: By the way, why you are using 2 versions of jQuery? In your head element, you are adding `jquery-3.3.1` and in your body part you adding `jquery-1.11.0`

Comment: Yes it surprised me too but since it was like that in the tutorial i didn't try to change it.. i'll try

Comment: @LéonardFONTAINE `slick.css` and `slick.min.js` Where these files are located? Have you downloaded these files on your own server? if yes, then please check the file's path.

Comment: slick.css and slick.min.css are downloaded in /slick-1.8.1/slick

Comment: Can you provide the full path of both files?

Comment: AH ! okay it's just me i'm stupid, i've changed the path to slick-1.8.1/slick/slick.css and now it works, they don't give the good link in the tuto and i didn't even verifyed it. Thanks guys anyway :)

Answer (score -1):

Your setup seems to be fine - as I've replaced your links with online CDNs and they seem to be working. You also only need the one link to jQuery (in the footer). The one in the header isn't needed as you can see from the example I've given below.

Have you made sure all your links to the scripts/styles are correct? You can use the online links (CDNs), like I have in my answer below, to make your life a little easier and avoid these problems in future :)

```js
$('.testslicktrack').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
</head>

<div class="testslicktrack">
  <div>
    <h4>test1</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>test2</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>test3</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>test4</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>test5</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>test6</h4>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was just a problem with the path.

Comment: @LéonardFONTAINE Ah yes thought so - you can use the online links above to make it a little easier for yourself and avoid the problem in the future :)

Comment: Questions that are solved by correcting a typo should be deleted. Delete this answer so @LéonardFONTAINE can remove the question.

Comment: @MiXT4PE I'm not correcting a typo - i'm offering a different solution to his problem?

Comment: @coops What solution is there to offer? It is working now and you only replaced the links with different ones. That's a workaround at best.

Comment: @MiXT4PE No, the tutorial gave on the website doesn't provide the good links so this might happen to other people who didn't verify it and it might be useful to them :)

Comment: @coops I disagree. CDNs are not applicable in every scenario. The tutorial is not wrong for using local resources which might be preferred in some use cases.

Comment: Ok, you're allowed to disagree @MiXT4PE, but it doesn't make my answer incorrect or useless? There are many benefits of using CDNs, I often find them quicker to load and using them removes the inaccuracies/mistakes in getting the path link wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Reason of the error is that the files don't exist in the path which is used under the tutorial he followed. Just defining the correct path fixes the issue.

@LéonardFONTAINE already corrected that out just adding here so other users may see the answers if they found some sort of this issue.

Comment: Questions that are solved by correcting a typo should be deleted as they provide no additional value. Delete this answer so @LéonardFONTAINE can remove the question.